# Display quantity of simple product using sku

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Following is the code to get stock quantity by using product Id.

```
<?php 
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId());
    echo (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
?>
```

I need to get the same result using product `SKU`.
Is it possible to retrieve the data using above method?

or else how can I Iterate the data if I follow the below path?

```
$productsku = $_item->getSku();
$skuu = $productsku;    
$_productCart = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $skuu);
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_productCart);
```

How can I iterate the stock quantity from $stock?

Comment: Try $_productCart = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $skuu);
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_productCart);  
echo $stock->getQty();

Answer (score 1):

```
$sku = "Your sku";
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
Zend_Debug::dump($stock->getData());

echo $stock->getQty();
echo $stock->getMinQty();
echo $stock->getMinSaleQty();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer on my own by adding to the existing  code below.

```
$productsku = $_item->getSku();  
$_productCart = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $$productsku);
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_productCart);
```

I was getting an array of details from the above code.
From that I did the following way.

```
$totalQty =  $stock['qty'];
 echo $totalQty;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   echo 'Quantity: '.(int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?>
```